# How to get diffs for Gerrit IDs?

Tags: git, tags, diff, gerrit

In a development forum (Rockbox firmware), a contributor referenced some numbers like g#1552, g#1557, g#1558 and said that these are related to Gerrit and can be used to get the 'requisite patches' for his build. Where is one supposed to put these numbers to get the actual patches? I am not too familiar with Gerrit, but from what I know, it is used to push changes, and not to pull diffs from a repository.

Comment: See https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-patch

Comment: I still don't see where to put these numbers. Are they the change ID? The revision ID? Do I have to keep the 'g#' prefix? Where is the project name, I know its URL in git, but does it apply here? Is there a command line tool to get the patches, or do I have to manually form an URL from pieces to get the patches?

Comment: Most likely the legacy number in https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#change-id . It's a unique number/ticket for every reviewed patch set. It's also the main key in Gerrit database. With this number, you can get everything via Gerrit's restapi. The first link is one of the apis. As to the usage of Gerrit restapi, see https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/dev-rest-api.html.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Access the Gerrit UI using an Internet Browser (https://GERRIT-SERVER)
2. Paste the change number (only the number, without the "g#") at the search field
3. Click on ***Search*** button

You'll get the change page with all information about it (author, date, branch, commit log, changed files, etc).

If you want to bring this change to your local repository do the following:

1. Click on ***Download*** button
2. Click on ***Copy to clipboard*** button (right side) of the Checkout option
3. Execute this command on your local repository

Comment: Thank you for the most comprehensive reply! I was able to find the gerrit server and download the patches. Also thanks for the checkout command hint, this makes getting the changes even simpler.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept the answer? Thanks!